# Axios dont post data to last column in SQL Lite (React)

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, axios

As in the title. I am doing a simple sing up post request using axios. I am getting successful response 200. Everything works fine except the last column `roles`. Roles column in SQL Lite is of type varchar just like email and password. Exactly the same but data is not inserted there. Any ideas what is the problem?

```
 const onPost = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
await axios
  .post("/data/users", {
    email: email,
    password: password,
    roles: "user",
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

// submitLogin(email, password);
};
```

[image: SQL Lite image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Issue was with the database user.js config file. User argument was missing in function.

```
server.post("/data/users", (request, response) => {
let user = request.body;
let encryptedPassword = encrypt(user.password);
let result;
try {
  result = db
    .prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, roles) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    .run([user.email, encryptedPassword, user.roles]);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
response.json(result);
});
```